# Might the practical nature of this chemistry problem make it suitable for Eng.SE?

Tags: discussion

I've asked the following question on chemistry.SE:

https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/74444/etching-brass-methods-for-simple-disposing-substances-with-household-waste

It's had very little attention, and I'm wondering if it would have been better to ask it here - principally because perhaps the element of methods for disposal of waste strike me as an engineering domain problem, as it's a more practical issue? (Not that practical implies engineering).

Also, I suppose Eng.SE includes chemical engineering? Perhaps the sometimes blurry boundaries of SE sites as well as engineering disciplines mean the question could, or even should, have been asked here?

Answer (score 3):

I think that the challenge of that question is that in your title you're essentially asking "design a process for me."  You narrow that when you ask for a specific etching material, but then broaden it back out when you're asking for a disposal process.

> What would be a good choice of etchant? And what would the process be for using and disposing of the waste / bi-products?

StackExchange works best with focused Q&A.  As currently phrased, I think that your question is "too broad" for this site and perhaps for Chemistry as well.

I would suggest narrowing the question on Chemistry to focusing on identifying a suitable etchant.  Once you get an answer there, do your research and possibly ask another question regarding disposal, if necessary.